# How can we write data from Spark Java to Influxdb mesurement using Datasets?

Tags: java, apache-spark, time-series, dataset, influxdb

I'm working on application that generates a dataset and I would like to save results into a influxdb database, but I didn't find anything about it. Please does anyone have any idea where can I start?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to push data from you application to InfluxDB.

1. You can use a InfluxDB client library to integrate to InfluxDB from your application. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java is one of such library for JAVA
2. You can write the data to a log file and use Telegraf client to push data to InfluxDB.
3. You can write the data to log file in JSON/CSV or InfluxDB specific line protocol. Please see the [docs](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_INPUT.md) to know what are the input data formats supported by Telegraf

Hope this answer helps